# Unable to add blade component using Appserviceprovider in laravel

Tags: laravel

This is my Appserviceprovider code.

```
 public function boot()
    {
        Blade::component('components.badge', 'badge');
        //also tried app.components.badge  
     
    }
```

And this is my component badge.blade.php inside component folder in views folder

```
<div class="badge badge-{{ $type ?? 'success' }}">
    {{ $slot }}
</div>
```

And this is where m trying to display the component

```
 @badge(['type' => 'primary'])
        New!
 @endbadge
```

This is what m getting as an output on my page
@badge(['type' => 'primary']) New! @endbadge

It is working when m using this

```
@component('components.badge', ['type' => 'primary'])
        New!
@endcomponent
```

[image]

Comment: so you want to create a blade directive?

Comment: what is your component view path?

Comment: resource/views/components/badge.blade.php is my component path @umefarooq

Comment: @lagbox i want to display it on my page.. right now it not rendering as i mentioned in the question.. it is not loading the component but instead showing everything as text. Madding an image to the questing so that it is clear

Comment: right below the time you can see how it is showing when m using @badge alias but when m using @component(in the title) it is working fine

Comment: what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: run following artisan command php artisan cache:clear and php artisan  clear-compiled will removed cache app service provider than you will have component available for you

Comment: @lagbox 7.18 laravel version

Comment: its still showing the same result @umefarooq

Comment: i dont see where in the 7.x docs it shows calling a component through a directive, seems it only shows the new tag syntax

Comment: i was following a lecture of laravel..  this is exactly what he did.. but it didnt worked tried watching it several times just incase if i have missed anything. but didnt worked.. wont remove the question just incase someone know whats wrong in here.. will do it in a usual way using @component

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `AppServiceProvider::boot()`, change:

```
Blade::component('components.file','tag')
```

to

```
Blade::aliasComponent('components.file','tag')
```

Run `php artisan view:clear` to clear view cache.

Answer (score 1):

The Blade::component method has to be renamed to Blade::aliasComponent in Laravel Framework 7.0

Using Blade::aliasComponent to give an alias to an anonymous component, the alias is not registered and an exception is thrown.
Only In your App service provider, aliase that component as 'badge':
/* AppServiceProvider.php */

From

```
Blade::component('components.badge', 'badge');
```

To

```
Blade::aliasComponent('components.badge', 'badge')
```